# DbMigrator in EF Code First Database Migrations needs access to master Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I am using the following code to check if there are any pending EF DB migrations.

```
var dbConnectionInfo = new DbConnectionInfo(dbConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");
var migratorConfig = new Configuration
{
    TargetDatabase = dbConnectionInfo
};
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(migratorConfig);
// the following line throws SqlException when run against SQL Server in Azure
var pendingMigrations = dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
var pendingMigrationsCount = pendingMigrations.Count;
```

It fails when I use it against a SQL DB in Azure. **Note** that sql users cannot be assigned Default Database in the SQL Server versions in Azure.

Is there a fix or work-around for this?

**Exception:**

> The server principal "O-someuser" is not able to access the database
>   "**master**" under the current security context. Database '**master**' on
>   server 'xyz.westus1-a.worker.database.windows.net' is not currently
>   available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem
>   persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session
>   tracing ID of 'blah blah'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we could connect to the Azure SQL server. Please have a try to  create a new login to try it. It works correctly for me. Detail info please refer to the screenshot.

> The default admin user is also worked for me.

[image]

[image]